# How to set a specific Number as Next ID and Its Continuation to use as Primary Key on Creation of Next Record On wards in PL-SQL in my Rails-4 App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, plsql

If my Question title is not clear, 
Let me details it more:
In my rails application, in  local(development) I am using PL-SQL as my databse, and there is a Customer table where the Primary ID starts from 1,2,3.......so on. Till I start using the same database in Local(development) & Production there was no problem in creating customers, so after I started running Local(development) & Production in parallel with same DB many of the time customer creations fails as ID's trying to create as Duplicate. So how can I set in my Local/Production to change the next Index to start with for the ID into another number to avoid this conflict. ?

Eg: I want to continue using(1,2.....etc) the ID in Local & in production I want to set the next Id from 50000 on wards and continuation.

Comment: So both development and production environments are using the same DB, same table?

Comment: @Hawk yes both development and production environments are using the same DB

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you have development environment and live environment both linked to the same Database and same table (say the table name is customer_tab, and the primary id column is cus_id).

Although, this is highly not recommended practice, but if you want to have the primary id be in sequence regardless where the insert is coming from (live or dev), then you can use sequence and triggers. That is, insert statement will not insert the primary id, rather it will leave it null. However, on insert, you run the trigger that uses the sequence numbers. Something like this:

```
/*Create sequence*/
create sequence customer_tab_seq
start with 5000
increment by 1;

/*Create trigger*/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER customer_tab_tri
BEFORE INSERT ON customer_tab
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF INSERTING THEN
IF :NEW.cus_id IS NULL THEN
SELECT customer_tab_seq.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.cus_id FROM DUAL;
END IF;
END IF;
END;
/
```

In this case, first row inserted will be given 5000 (regardless if it is from live or dev), the second will be given 5001 (regardless if it is from live or dev). And it will save you future conflicts.

Comment: @PraveenGeorge in the same place you code creating the table